# ASP.NET JQuery Plugin initialization error

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use the jquery plugin Bootstrap Colorpickerplus but I get the following errors :

"colorInput.colorpicker is not a function"

"$(...).colorpickerplus is not a function"

I have inserted JQuery, colorpicker js & css file.
Do I need colorpicker files to use colorpickerplus ?

This is how I initialize the plugin :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Couleur_grille').colorpickerplus();
    $('#Couleur_grille').on('changeColor', function(e){
        if(e.color==null) {
            $('.color-fill-icon', $(this)).addClass('colorpicker-color');
        } else {
            $('.color-fill-icon', $(this)).removeClass('colorpicker-color');
            $('.color-fill-icon', $(this)).css('background-color', e.color);
        }
    });
});
```

My input to bind :

```
<input type="button" id="Couleur_grille" />
```

The plugin I am trying to use : http://www.jqueryrain.com/?HTPdFszp

Answer (score 0):

As this plugin is an extension for Bootstrap colorpicker you will need to include http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js and http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css on your page.

You can look for an example on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zzzhan/6fdqqsb8/

```
var demo1 = $('#demo1');
    demo1.colorpickerplus();
    demo1.on('changeColor', function(e){
        if(e.color==null)
        $(this).val(e.color).css('background-color', '#fff');//tranparent
        else
        $(this).val(e.color).css('background-color', e.color);
    });
```

Comment: I was also also facing the same problem. After including proper files it is not giving any error, but color picker is also not opening on click of text field.

I also checked jsfiddle provided, there also same problem I've observed.

Any idea what can be wrong here?

Comment: @pooja, did you include Jqery, bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css in your page?

Comment: Yes, I did. But no luck

Comment: @pooja Ok, so I've inspected code of this plugin and it won't work properly in jsfiddle. Probably it worked before. It uses function($) (document ready check) to verify that DOM is ready, but jsfiddle uses iframe to load body, which will be availbe after document.load. That's why it won't run properly in jsfiddle.